# Adding values into an empty list

Tags: python, list

I have a simple question that I can't seem to figure out and I've tried over a week. I am very new to python and am trying to work my way through a MOOC through the University of Helsinki. The issue is quite simple.

step 1: Create an new variable basename that contains text "Station"

```
basename = "Station"
```

step 2 create new variable filenames that is an empty list

```
filenames = []
```

step 3: Iterate over the number range 0-20 and

Create a variable `station` that contains the 1) text from `basename` variable, 2) the number, and 3) the file extension `.txt`. Add the content of `station` to `filenames` list which should have following content in the end:

```
['Station_0.txt', 'Station_1.txt', 'Station_2.txt', 'Station_3.txt',
 'Station_4.txt', 'Station_5.txt', 'Station_6.txt', 'Station_7.txt',
 'Station_8.txt', 'Station_9.txt', 'Station_10.txt', 'Station_11.txt',
 'Station_12.txt', 'Station_13.txt', 'Station_14.txt', 'Station_15.txt',
 'Station_16.txt', 'Station_17.txt', 'Station_18.txt', 'Station_19.txt',
 'Station_20.txt']
```

This is what I've tried, and it will prints out the values that I want

```
for station in range(21):
    print(basename, '_', station, '.txt', sep='')
Station_0.txt
Station_1.txt
Station_2.txt
Station_3.txt
Station_4.txt
Station_5.txt
Station_6.txt
Station_7.txt
Station_8.txt
Station_9.txt
Station_10.txt
Station_11.txt
Station_12.txt
Station_13.txt
Station_14.txt
Station_15.txt
Station_16.txt
Station_17.txt
Station_18.txt
Station_19.txt
Station_20.txt
```

Now how the heck do I get those values into the empty list? I know I didn't create a new variable station, and can't seem to figure out how to add the content of it into the filenames variable

Comment: Append them to the list instead of printing them.

Comment: New code then is 
for i in range(21):
    filenames.append(basename, '_', i, '.txt', sep='')

Which results in 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b4099cc35602> in <module>
      1 # YOUR CODE HERE
      2 for i in range(21):
----> 3     filenames.append(basename, '_', i, '.txt', sep='')

TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Just for fun (as it's clearly not [yet] part of your exercise): `filenames = ['Station_%d.txt' % i for i in range(21)]`. Python can be both concise *and* very expressive at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation to create the `station` variable. Then append it to the list.

```
for i in range(21):
    station = basename + '_' + str(i) + '.txt'
    filenames.append(station)
print(filenames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the filenames to a list with a loop:

```
for i in range(21):
    filenames.append(f'{basename}_{i}.txt')
```

Or you can simply use a list comprehension:

```
filenames = ['Station_'+str(i)+'.txt' for i in range(21)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually add them to the `filenames` list. Right now you are just printing them out to the console. So instead of `print(basename, '_', station, '.txt', sep='')` do `filenames.append(basename + '_' + station + '.txt')`